# How to uninstall eclipse core components?

Tags: eclipse, p2

I will be glad, if my eclipse didn't have the mylyn and the cvs modules. I don't want them, I want them to get out. But the eclipse package management doesn't let me their removal.

I tried already to remove them from the packages & features directory, but it didn't work.

An ideal solution were, if existed some flag or settings in the eclipse packages, which contained the information from a package if it is removable.

Yes, I know that eclipse loads these packages only on need, but I want to remove, delete them forever and sow their place with salt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Harsh. The simplest thing to do then is to start with the bare Eclipse Platform Runtime Binary download then add the things you *do* want.

http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops4/R-4.3.1-201309111000/

Answer (score 1):

Build your custom installation by using the p2.director application (from an SDK download) to install exactly those features you like to have. [p2.director help](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/p2_director.html)

General description (accessing all kepler simultaneous release repos). Mind the the appendix <.feature.group> for features you want to install.

```
c:\<eclipse-sdk>\eclipsec.exe -application org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director -repository http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.3,http://download.eclipse.org/releases/kepler,http://download.eclipse.org/technology/epp/packages/kepler -installIU <feature1>.feature.group,<feature1>.feature.group,<bundleX>,<bundleY> -destination c:/eclipse -profile SDKProfile
```

concrete example installing only the SDK on windows (be patient for the download)

```
F:\__TEST\eclipse-SDK-4.3-win32-x86_64\eclipse\eclipsec.exe -application org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director -repository http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.3,http://download.eclipse.org/releases/kepler,http://download.eclipse.org/technology/epp/packages/kepler -installIU org.eclipse.sdk.ide -destination c:/eclipse -profile SDKProfile
```

You find the resulting installed product inside the destination `c:/eclipse`.